# ERROR in multi ./main.js . Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/user/workspace/webpack'

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I am facing issues while bundling 2 independent javascript files.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>experiment</title>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="new.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<button onclick="firstButton();">firstButton</button>
<button onclick="secondButton();">secondtButton</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
function firstButton() {

console.log("First Button");    
}
```

**new.js**

```
function secondButton(){
    alert("Second Button");
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    filename: './bundle.js'
  }
};
```

when running **webpack .** command then getting this error on terminal

```
Hash: 8a3cc31d526703c3b9fa
Version: webpack 2.5.1
Time: 88ms
      Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
./bundle.js  2.91 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./main.js 57 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] multi ./main.js . 40 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in multi ./main.js .
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/user/workspace/webpack' in '/home/user/workspace/webpack'
 @ multi ./main.js .
```

also i tried this **webpack.config.js**

```
const config = {
  entry: {
    a : './main.js' ,
    b : './new.js'
  } ,
   output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: '/home/user/workspace/webpack'
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

this is the error i am getting ..

```
user@user-ThinkPad-T420s:~/workspace/webpack$ webpack .
Hash: 44a14163f4c0c760c3ad
Version: webpack 2.5.1
Time: 89ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  2.69 kB       0  [emitted]  b
   [0] ./main.js 57 bytes {1} [built]
   [1] ./new.js 51 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/user/workspace/webpack' in '/home/user/workspace/webpack'

ERROR in chunk a [entry]
bundle.js
Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any argument to the webpack CLI is interpreted as an entry point (see [Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/)). When you run:

```
webpack .
```

the `.` corresponds to the current directory and webpack tries to resolve a module from it, which should be used as an entry point.

You're already configuring the entry points in your webpack config, therefore you should run webpack without any arguments:

```
webpack
```

Comment: i am still facing issues.. can you help me resolve further ?

Comment: Each entry point creates a separate bundle, so you have to use different output names, e.g. `filename: '[name].bundle.js'`. For more information see [`output.filename`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename).

Comment: well..it worked and now got to bundle files ..
a.bundle.js and b.bundle.js

Comment: is it possible to bundle these two independent files to one single js without changing code ?

Comment: You can use an array as entry `entry: ['./main.js', './new.js']`.

Comment: it got bundled as one single file but now my js in not working :-/